# How to rewrite "something/test?id=test" to "test.php?id=test" in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to rewrite `something/test?id=test` to `test.php?id=test` in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^v1/games/list?sortToken=(.*)$ /juicy.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Nothing works!

Comment: did you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^v1/games/list?sortToken=(.*)$ /juicy.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. To match the query string you need to use an additional *condition* and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

> How to rewrite `something/test?id=test` to `test.php?id=test`

However, the example given in the question is quite different to the rewrite implied by your `RewriteRule` attempt?

To rewrite this example, you could use something like this:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(test)$ $1.php [L]
```

The above will internally rewrite `/<something>/test?id=test` to `test.php?id=test`. The query string is passed through by default, so this matches *any* query string.

However, to rewrite `/v1/games/list?sortToken=<something>` to `/juicy.php?id=<something>` (as implied by your "attempt"), you would need to do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sortToken=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^v1/games/list$ juicy.php?id=%1 [NE,L]
```